# Setting the Viewbox so that the inline SVG will "Snap" to the size of the containing element?

Tags: inkscape, svg, html

I created this simple inline SVG by saving as "Optimized SVG" in inkscape.  Prior to saving I set the size to 200X200px.

```
    <div style="width: 200px; background-color: red;">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
     <g>
      <path class="fs-logo-fill" d="m71.679 40.782v52.917h52.917v-52.917zm26.458 7.2166a19.242 19.242 0 0 1 19.242 19.242 19.242 19.242 0 0 1-19.242 19.242 19.242 19.242 0 0 1-19.242-19.242 19.242 19.242 0 0 1 19.242-19.242z"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

I then put it inside a the `div` element seen that has a width of `200px`.

This is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/oleersoy/pen/dLxvEJ

As can be seen the red div is a lot larger than the inline svg rendering.  How do we set the viewbox parameters so that the inline SVG will always fit the size of the containing element?

[Also asked this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958117/setting-the-viewbox-so-that-the-inline-svg-will-snap-to-the-size-of-the-contai/55958379?noredirect=1#comment98571159_55958379) and we are getting closer.  Anyone know if we can set the viewbox parameters we want while saving?

Comment: I would just scale the object so it fits the 200x200px artboard. Is there a reason why you can't do that?

Comment: Hm @Wolff - You may have a perfectly valid point here!  I tried saving with a 200X200px square to a 200X200px artboard, and then removing the height and width attributes on the svg element so it looks like this `<svg
   viewBox="0 0 52.916665 52.916668"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1434">
` and I think that works.  Do you want to provide the answer and I can give you credit?

Comment: This might be a lesson in not overthinking it :)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what i meant. I would select the artwork (the blue shape) and scale it so it's 200x200px.

Comment: Hmmm - Maybe - but I think you're trick works for what I want.  I want it to be responsive - so that if I change the outer div, then the SVG shape also changes automatically - in other words I want to control the height and width of the SVG by controlling the containing dimensions of the html element.  Sound OK?

Comment: That's more of a css question? Can't you just use the svg as *background-image* and set *background-size* to *cover*? Only works if your artwork is the same size as the svg.

Comment: This question has been asked here, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958117/setting-the-viewbox-so-that-the-inline-svg-will-snap-to-the-size-of-the-contai and has an accepted answer there.

Comment: I could use `background-image` but inline SVG is better and we can do more with it like change colors using CSS etc: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=af4ZQJ14yu8&t

Comment: The SO accepted answer is a little different - I think the answer Wolff is hinting at is better, because it produces a perfect fit.  In other words as long as the Inkscape canvas is exactly the same size as the drawing, we don't have to figure out the ViewBox parameters

Comment: Here's a pen https://codepen.io/oleersoy/pen/xevpOw

Comment: I saved the square to 200By200PX and set the canvas to the same size.  Then I removed the opacity attributes etc from the raw SVG and added a class attribute.  You can see that we can control the color of the SVG path using CSS `fs-logo-fill`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Wolff hint as long as we set the canvas size to the same size as the drawing, then viewbox takes care of itself.  In other words it has the right parameters to fit inside a div responsively and we are done.  Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/oleersoy/pen/xevpOw

Note that we are setting the color of the SVG using the css class `fs-logo-fill`.  If we change the width and height of the containing div, the inline SVG resizes itself automatically, so now we have inline SVG that resizes automatically and we can set CSS classes on the paths to control fill and stroke colors, effects, etc.